# magento custom order attribute value not saving

Tags: magento

I created an attribute for order and quote using installer script. Those can be seen in the entity_attribute table. In the checkout i want to set value and save it with the order. I created an event and observer function. But value wont saving. Any help please.

config.xml

```
<sales_order_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <clickandcollect_save_location_orderattributes>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>Balance_Clickandcollect_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>saveLocationOrderattributes</method>
                    </clickandcollect_save_location_orderattributes>
                </observers>
</sales_order_save_after>
```

Observer.php

```
public function saveLocationOrderattributes($observer){
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        //$quote = $event->getQuote();
        $order->setLocation('1');
}
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this. I cannot understand where did i make mistake.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are missing **save** method

you must have to change your observer code as below

```
public function saveLocationOrderattributes($observer){
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        //$quote = $event->getQuote();

       //or load the order
        $order_id = $order->getId();
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
        $order->setLocation('1');
        $order->save();

}
```

so it will save your order updated value.

hope this will help you

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. Earlier i added the save() but then i got an error saying memory exceeded :( what should i do for that. In my php.ini memory has put as 168M

Comment: you can increase it up to `256M` or `512M` might be work for you. Also see my updated code.

Comment: Its not working. Isn't there any other solution. What i want is save order attribute value in the checkout. Any help...

Comment: Are you getting order information in your actual observer ? like order id and all

Comment: yes order information are getting and they are saving too

Comment: it seems that you have to follow for you custom attribute http://chillydraji.wordpress.com/2014/03/03/how-to-create-new-attribute-to-order-in-magento/

Comment: it should work for you or might be you are missing something in your custom attribute creation and save process :(

Comment: Hi thank you for help. Yes that works. I have made a mistake in the installer script. I have use my setup model which i mentioned in the config.xml file instead of $installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup; Thank you so much...

Answer (score 1):

Your order->save() goes back to sales_order_save_after and makes an infinite loop. Try this, I added a registry key so it won't save the attribute and order after your order->save() call

```
public function saveLocationOrderattributes($observer){
        if(!Mage::registry('afterOrderSave'))
        {
            Mage::register('afterOrderSave');
            $event = $observer->getEvent();
            $order = $event->getOrder();
            $order->setLocation('1');
            $order->save();
        }
    }
```